# Requiring a Ruby Gem in Ruby Script breaks Cron Job Execution

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cron, rvm

I'm trying to run a cron job using Gems. I've installed ruby via RVM and when I require a gem it breaks the cron job. I've tried requiring two totally different gems, PG / Pry, and when I require either, the cronjob doesn't complete. Here is the "testing code" that works fine:

```
open('/home/log.log', 'a') do |f|
  f.puts Time.now.to_s
end
```

Here is how I setup the cronjob:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby /home/test1.rb
```

I can see new output every minute. And when I add a require gem line at the top, it then breaks, but only when run through cron:

```
require 'pg'

open('/home/log.log', 'a') do |f|
  f.puts Time.now.to_s
end
```

The cronjob runs (I can see it execute in the sys log), but never completes (no output ever makes it into the text file). I've tried this on two separate servers one Debian, one CentOS, and both have the same issue. Oddly enough this only affects the cron job, if I run the same ruby file from console: /home/test1.rb it will work just fine.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Do you have a `RUBYLIB` environment variable problem? The various search paths when running a cron job rarely match the ones that are used in an interactive shell.

Comment: I don't think I have a RUBYLIB environment variable set in any of my configs. I did the following to check. ruby -e "puts $:" in IRB, then I created a ruby script that would save the output of that to a file and ran it through the cron job. The output of both was exactly the same. That means the Rubylib environment variable shouldn't be the problem, right?

Comment: @muistooshort - I checked to see if it would break if I required "pry" instead of "pg" and sure enough. So I'm going to modify the question a bit to reflect that.

Comment: So it breaks no matter what you `require`? That smells like a path problem of sort. When you're running in a normal shell, it looks like you're going through RVM so it is probably setting up your environment for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I will try this first thing in the morning (it's 5am here).

Comment: Do some googling for "rvm cron", this is probably a common problem. Sleep well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to setup your crontab with rvm e.g:

rvm cron setup

With that rvm sets your environment variables in your crontab file

then you have a crontab file having this at the top:

```
PATH="/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/"
rvm_env_string='ruby-1.9.3-p194'
rvm_path='/usr/local/rvm'
rvm_ruby_string='ruby-1.9.3-p194'
RUBY_VERSION='ruby-1.9.3-p194'
GEM_HOME='/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194'
GEM_PATH='/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global'
MY_RUBY_HOME='/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194'
IRBRC='/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/.irbrc'
```

Then you can stick your crontask beneath it

Comment: Just to simplify the answer a bit: Run this command in console "rvm cron setup" and everything will magically work! Thank you for this :)

Comment: @newUserNameHere someone told me his console freezes when he runs "rvm cron setup" then secondly I am not sure if rvm reorders your crontab, so you might need to view it to see how it looks afterwards, that's why I put a template for aid :-)

Comment: Ahhh.. I see. +1 for great info. And thanks again for the solution, I was going nuts trying to figure this out.

Comment: Tip: `rvm cron setup` fails for some people (like me), but you can get all the values for these variables by just saying `echo $VARIABLENAME` and manually enter them into the crontab. Works like a charm!