# Ruby and Crontab - Script is not producing results

Tags: ruby, ubuntu-12.04, cron

I've looked for answers to this already without avail, so I turn here.
I'm running Ubuntu 12.04LTS, using RVM, running ruby 2.0.0p353.
I've written a script that, in a nutshell, modifies a file. Let's call this file access.txt.
Whenever I run the script by hand, it works beautifully, and modifies the file.

However, when I run this via crontab, it does not update the file. This is currently what I have in crontab.
0 * * * * /path/to/script.rb

I should also note that despite it being bad practice, I am running this as root.
I've also tried specifying it to run within a bash file.
0 * * * * /path/to/bash.sh

This also produces no results.
The cron log shows these jobs as running, and both have executable permissions.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: it is path related issues, cron can't locate your ruby env variables

Comment: I swear I did a search for this before I posted it and now I'm seeing other related questions. I apologize for the re-post if this is what this is.

Comment: I've set it to use #!/usr/bin/env ruby but it still doesn't work.

Comment: look at this answer I gave to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20672583/requiring-a-ruby-gem-in-ruby-script-breaks-cron-job-execution/20673953#20673953 I hope it helps

Comment: Check out [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) if you don't want to write the crontab file by hand.

Comment: bjhaid's solution worked brilliantly. Thanks!