# Using cron and ruby

Tags: ruby, cron, rubygems

**OS: Mac OS X 10.10.3; 
Ruby version: 2.2.0;**

I have a problem with using cron, that launches ruby script.
Problem: cron launches ruby script, but nothing happened. That cron says in its logs (script requires mongo gem) :

```
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- mongo (LoadError)
from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/username/project_path/main.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

Cron settings:

```
SHELL = /bin/bash
MAILTO = username
* * * * * /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/default/bin/ruby    /Users/username/project_path/main.rb
```

So ruby can't load gem, while the script was launched by cron, but when I launch it from the IDE or terminal, it works without problems

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20672583/requiring-a-ruby-gem-in-ruby-script-breaks-cron-job-execution

Comment: @diego.greyrobot I saw this solution, but it only breaks my config :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. After a couple of hours I finally solved this problem. And the solution is very easy. I don't know, why it's working only that way.
So, the solution:

1.Create bash script with this content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/wrappers/ruby    /path/to/your/ruby_script.rb
```

2. Configure cron file:

```
SHELL = /bin/bash
* * * * * /path/to/created/at/first/step/bash_script.sh
```

That's all!
It's working for me!

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem. Basically the environment in which your `cron` job is running is different from the environment in your IDE / terminal.

You need to investigate solutions along [these lines](https://coderwall.com/p/vhv8aw/getting-ruby-scripts-working-with-bundler-rvm-and-cron). Understanding what's going on will involve learning more about cron, users, and other related topics.

Comment: I read all instructions in the Internet, including this. Finally I solved this problem by the stupid solution. This solution I wrote in answer at my own question